# socket authentication in mobile app

Tags: node.js, sockets, cordova, redis, socket.io

I'm wondering how to properly authenticate a user using sockets and cordova.

Currently, the following happens:

1. User registers or logs in using an normal ajax command, sending `email` and `password`
2. I send back an access token and their email, which is stored in `localstorage` on the phone and as `email => accesstoken` in redis
3. The user then sends a connection request to the socket.io server, something like (**client side**):

---

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.50.3:8080/');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('init', { email: 'email@email.com', token: '12ueno1' });
});
```

4. I then check on the backend if that access token and email are in my redis server, if they are, I start listening for any commands sent by the client like so (**server side**):

---

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    schema = mongoose.Schema,
    userModel = require('./models/user'),
    lobbyModel = require('./models/lobby'),
    redis = require('redis').createClient();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('init', function(data){
        // here, we check for an init command which will have an email and access token
        // if it's there, we put the user into a room and let them wait for data
        redis.get(data.email, function(err, reply){
            if(reply === data.token){

                // get into room
                var roomKey = data.email;
                socket.join(roomKey);

                // get user
                var user;
                userModel.findOne({ email: data.email }, function(err, doc){
                    user = doc;
                });

                socket.in(roomKey).on('create_lobby', function(data){
                    // do stuff for creating a lobby and then send back the data
                    io.sockets.in(roomKey).emit('created_lobby', {
                        email: user.email
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

5. Now authenticated, the user can send commands like (**client side**):

---

```
socket.on('create_lobby', { name: 'test' });
```

Now, this works fine, I'm just wondering if I'm going at it the right way, or if I'm creating an insecure system.

Comment: you're going to use https in production, right?

Comment: @JohnMee yeah, I will be :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather late but I've only just come across this question.

The answer is that the approach *is* insecure.

Firstly, the token isn't being validated.

Secondly, there is no timeout check.

Comment: The token would be authenticated. On the client trying to connect to the socket, it fetches the email from redis and gets the value (which is the token) then you do `if(reply === data.token){`. What do you mean by a timeout check?

Comment: Tokens often have no checks as to whether they are still coming from the original authenticator client, this can leave them open to MiTM interception and replay attacks. Typically therefore, token lifespans are restricted to reduce that risk. In addition, user logins are also typically restricted to a given timespan, this may often be extended by users continuing to interact with the system but you probably need to have a limit.

Comment: That's what I assumed you meant. Redis has built in lifespan for entries, so we dont need to do compares on dates in the code, we just expire entries in redis after X amount of time and get the client to reauthenticate.